# How to find out what caused lag/freeze and self-reboot?

Tags: freeze, xubuntu

- Xubuntu 14.04
- FF 39.0, packaged by Canonical

I just experienced my machine practically freeze up and not reacting not any input. The mouse pointer moved like 2 mm every 20 seconds and my CPU load thingie in the top task bar had one full bar out of four (I think I am talking about XFCE's "CPU load" widget here). This happened while I was reading the tab about the security & cryptography parts of the iPhone on this official [Apple page](http://www.apple.com/iphone/why-theres-iphone/) (just saying what I did, nothing else).

I tried logging in via TTY1 but it did not take any login info I typed in. Actually, it took what I typed in at first (say `john` as a user) so I hit Enter after that but then nothing happened. Typing in the password for the user showed it in the TTY1, as it showed any other input. It also showed that `CTRL^C` part if I hit the combination to abort a process.

Switching back to the DE / TTY7 happened an eternity after I hit `CTRL + ALT + F7`. The Apple page was still visible.

Then I just watched the machine go on doing something for nearly 2 minutes, then I saw it restart itself. IIRC the message for the shutdown had the words "start" "stop" and "state" and "wait" in it.

I think what I am asking is: what exactly do I need to look for in `/var/log/syslog`? And do I need to look for something else?

- [syslog for the relevant time point](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11953981/)
- Explanations: I was the one disconnecting and reconnecting the ethernet cable, keyboard and mouse. It was some (lame) attempt to try and have Xubuntu recognize them again, to use them.

Comment: Which web browser is this?  How many cores does the machine have?

Comment: @goldilocks I edited the op. I use Firefox and my machine has 4 cores.

Comment: Try `grep "oom-killer" /var/log/syslog` and if that shows nothing try `grep -i oom ...` just to be sure.  You're checking to see if this was an out of memory (oom) issue; that shouldn't shut the system down but it will freeze it for a bit.   Regardless, whatever there is from syslog for that time period, if it looks at all relevant add it to your post.

Comment: BTW, I have CPU usage problems on some flash pages with firefox.  You should try this with flash disabled.

Comment: @goldilocks I was unable to use the keyboard for doing anything. The DE stopped responding after like 2 minutes, i.e. I could not open a terminal windows via a keyboard shortcut. I do not have flash installed for FF.

Comment: @goldilocks There was no output for the `grep`-commands.

Comment: @goldilocks I added the relevant part of `/var/ log/syslog`.

Comment: There's not a clear explanation there, but you can see the ethernet disconnects then reconnects, then the keyboard does the same thing, then  then the mouse does it four times, interlaced with the login process on tty1 being killed and respawned (init will do this).   Is this reproducible, i.e., if you go back to that Apple page now does it happen again?   You should run a CPU monitor somewhere so that when this happens, you can get some idea of what the usage is.   Presuming you were the one killing the login over and over, the rest of it might be explained by some kind of hardware fault.

Comment: @goldilocks I was the one disconnecting the ethernet cable and the periphery. I was trying to make them responsive again. Sorry I should have mentioned that. :(

Comment: @goldilocks Further testing showed the culprit is indeed http://www.apple.com/iphone/why-theres-iphone/#malware It is probably the animations causing some kind of buffer overload... or so. Must say I have no idea really.

Comment: For me here (Fedora 20) FF uses ~2-3x as much CPU as Chrome on that page, both of them spread across several cores, but nothing crippling -- this might imply it's a display driver.   Pretty sure there's no flash on that page, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: my ideas about what messages you might see don't seem to quite match with your report, so I'm probably missing something.

Basically I couldn't think of many reasons for software reboot faults, and you should definitely want to consider the hardware. Hypothetically if you extracted some sort of crash dump it would be very frustrating to interpret if the problem is actually hardware.  A RAM test would be a great idea at this point (Boot into `memtest86` or equivalent).  A cpu stress test would be good too to check for overheating.  From what you say you probably just want a few minutes running 4 `cpuburn` commands.

The biggest thing you should want to rule out, given your description, is that you'd run out of memory and the system was swapping itself to death.  This shouldn't cause a reboot.  The disk light would be on solidly.  And 100% cpu usage would not typically be expected, but some monitors might show a cpu in 100% "IO wait" state; this should be it's own colour.

I wouldn't expect you to see a message saying <error, rebooting now>.  You *might* just see some messages from a first or second fault before a triple fault and the screen goes black.  Those messages wouldn't get written to syslog - you'd need to set up an external kernel console.  (Serial port, or maybe netconsole).  Or try these [brief instructions to log exploiting EFI firmware, if you've got it](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/23554.html).  This may be a more practical option.  I'm not sure if it'll get enabled if you haven't mounted the pstore filesystem.  If you're interested in debugging kernels this seems a cool thing to look at.

---

Some configurations can initiate a reboot from software.  E.g. `panic=` kernel boot option and/or a watchdog timer.  systemd has a watchdog feature, probably with a timeout on the order of minutes.

I believe your OS defaults won't enable any of these.  (No `panic=`, and no systemd to start with). If you haven't enabled them, there's only a few software faults we expect to cause reboots.

If the kernel triggers a fault in the process of handling a fault from inside the kernel (on x86) the machine could reboot immediately.  A.k.a. "triple fault".  But other fatal kernel errors will "panic", print a message, and not reboot by default.

Otherwise we're thinking a completely wild error which happened to call into reboot code.  Probably this wouldn't repeat, unless you're getting lots of wild errors with weird effects anyway.

Maybe we're seeing memory corruption (caused during the busy period) eventually causing a triple fault.  Kernel messages during the busy period might cast light on that.